# How to use gsutil compose to concatenate Gogole storage objects in python code

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gsutil

I know the syntaxt for this
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite

If anyone could help with the actual python implementation on how to use this in my Python code. thnx

Else if there is a better way to export larger BQ data to GSC ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use Google Cloud Storage's Python client library, which has a `compose()` method to do this:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/db481bfdd6816d020d99df0d4caa307358ab1141/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L1537

Example usage can be seen in the integration test code:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/db481bfdd6816d020d99df0d4caa307358ab1141/storage/tests/system.py#L1011

Comment: Is there a better way to export BQ data into GSC without breaking it down ? i have data that may be more than 1.5/2 GB

Comment: Nope.  The docs state that, "BigQuery can export up to 1 GB of data to a single file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, you must export your data to multiple files."  Not sure what sort of pipeline you're using to process this data, but ideally, you'd create some sort of abstraction to stream/read your input from multiple files or GCS objects.